# Extract sentences in nested parentheses using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, parentheses

I have multiple `.txt` files in a directory. 
Here is a sample of **one** of my `.txt` files:

```
kkkkk;

  select xx("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'") jdfjhf:jhfjj from xxxx_x_xx_L ;
quit; 

/* 1.xxxxx FROM xxxx_x_Ex_x */ 
proc sql; ("TRUuuuth");
hhhjhfjs as fdsjfsj:
select * from djfkjd to jfkjs
(
SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and 
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))
 );


jjjjjj;

  select xx("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'") jdfjhf:jhfjj from xxxx_x_xx_L ;
quit; 

/* 1.xxxxx FROM xxxx_x_Ex_x */ ()
proc sql; ("CUuuiiiiuth");
hhhjhfjs as fdsjfsj:
select * from djfkjd to jfkjs
(SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and 
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))(( ))
 );
```

I am trying to extract all sentences in nested parentheses, in my `.txt` files.

I have tried multiple methods like [stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908686/extract-strings-inside-inconsistent-nested-brackets) parentheses but I get an error which says "list index out of range" when the code parses through one of the `.txt` files. I'm guessing its because there is nothing written in the brackets.

I have been trying it with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888951/python-regex-to-capture-all-words-within-nested-parentheses?noredirect=1#comment104062204_58888951) too, using this code:

```
with open('lan sample text file.txt','r') as fd:
    lines = fd.read()

    check = set()
    check.add("Select")
    check.add("select")
    check.add("SELECT")
    check.add("from")
    check.add("FROM")
    check.add("From")
    items=re.findall("(\(.*)\)",lines,re.MULTILINE)
    for x in items:
        print(x)
```

but my output is:

```
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'"
("TRUuuuth"
((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.
(xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.)
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'"
("CUuuiiiiuth"
((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.
(xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.)
```

My desired output should look something like this:

```
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'")
("TRUuuuth")
(
SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and 
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))
 )
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'")
("CUuuiiiiuth")
(SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and 
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))(( ))
 )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to match nested parentheses with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex)

Comment: @RonaldAaronson no it did not......that question is seemingly less complicated than what i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say my solution is not the optimised one, but it will solve your problem.

**Solution** (Just replace test.txt with your file name)

```
result = []
with open('test.txt','r') as fd:
    # To keep track of '(' and ')' parentheses
    parentheses_stack = []
    # To keep track of complete word wrapped by ()
    complete_word = []
    # Iterate through each line in file
    for words in fd.readlines():
        # Iterate each character in a line
        for char in list(words):
            # Initialise the parentheses_stack when you find the first open '(' 
            if char == '(':
                parentheses_stack.append(char)
            # Pop one open '(' from parentheses_stack when you find a ')'
            if char == ')':
                if not parentheses_stack = []:
                    parentheses_stack.pop()
                if parentheses_stack == []:
                    complete_word.append(char)
            # Collect characters in between the first '(' and last ')'
            if not parentheses_stack == []:
                complete_word.append(char)
            else:
                if not complete_word == []:
                    # Push the complete_word once you poped all '(' from parentheses_stack
                    result.append(''.join(complete_word))
                    complete_word = []



for res in result:
    print(res)
```

**Result:**

```
WS:python rameshrv$ python3 /Users/rameshrv/Documents/python/test.py
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'")
("TRUuuuth")
(
SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and 
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))
 )
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'")
()
("CUuuiiiiuth")
(SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and 
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))(( ))
 )
```

Comment: hey Ramesh! It does work! But i dont know if it'll work on my actual working file. I will get back to you when I've tried it at work tomorrow, but thank you so much for trying to resolve my situation. I truly appreciate it! I'll mark it as the answer once it works out! *fingers crossed*

Comment: my code has some minor bugs and i am trying to fix them. Will upload the clean code once i am done with the bugs.

Comment: Hi Ramesh, what if I run into an error that says: "IndexError: pop from empty list" when running your code? How could I work my way around this error?

Comment: Then you need to add a condition before parentheses_stack.pop() to check whether the parentheses_stack is empty.

Comment: i tried to put if words != "": before it but the error still happens

Comment: i edited the answer to handle the IndexError. Now it shouldn't throw any Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, this is a duplicate of [Python: How to match nested parentheses with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex), which shows several methods of handling nested parentheses, not all of which are regex-based. One way does require the `regex` module from the PYPI repository. If `text` contains the contents of the file, then the following should do what you want:

```
import regex as re

text = """kkkkk;

  select xx("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'") jdfjhf:jhfjj from xxxx_x_xx_L ;
quit;

/* 1.xxxxx FROM xxxx_x_Ex_x */
proc sql; ("TRUuuuth");
hhhjhfjs as fdsjfsj:
select * from djfkjd to jfkjs
(
SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))
 );


jjjjjj;

  select xx("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'") jdfjhf:jhfjj from xxxx_x_xx_L ;
quit;

/* 1.xxxxx FROM xxxx_x_Ex_x */ ()
proc sql; ("CUuuiiiiuth");
hhhjhfjs as fdsjfsj:
select * from djfkjd to jfkjs
(SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))(( ))
 );"""    

regex = re.compile(r"""
(?<rec> #capturing group rec
 \( #open parenthesis
 (?: #non-capturing group
    [^()]++ #anything but parenthesis one or more times without backtracking
  | #or
    (?&rec) #recursive substitute of group rec
 )*
 \) #close parenthesis
)
""", flags=re.VERBOSE)

for m in regex.finditer(text):
    groups = m.captures('rec')
    group = groups[-1] # the last group is the outermost nesting
    if re.match(r'^\(+\s*\)+$', group):
        continue # not interested in empty parentheses such as '( )'
    print(group)
```

Prints:

```
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'")
("TRUuuuth")
(
SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))
 )
("xE'", PUT(xx.xxxx.),"'")
("CUuuiiiiuth")
(SELECT abc AS abc1, abc_2_ AS efg, abc_fg, fkdkfj_vv, jjsflkl_ff, fjkdsf_jfkj
    FROM &xxx..xxx_xxx_xxE
where ((xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') gff &jfjfsj_jfjfj.) and
      (xxx(xx_ix as format 'xxxx-xx') lec &jgjsd_vnv.))(( ))
 )
```

Comment: Hi Ronald, this did not work, I ran into an error->  "error: unknown extension ?<r at position 2 (line 2, column 2)"

Comment: @pysduck Did you code `import regex as re`, as iI have it in the first line of the code above? You *do* need the `regex` package from the PyPi repository. I also added the definition of string variable `text`, just to make everything explicit.

Comment: ohhhh. I do not have that package. Sorry for not understanding that! But thank you for showing me something new:)

Comment: @psyduck It's easy to install: `pip install regex`. It also fixes some bugs in the standard `re` package depending on what version of Python you are running.